# Getting Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-timeline, review

I am fetching my timeline from Facebook and I successfully able to get my timeline but when I login with my friend's Facebook account I received the following error-

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I am the admin of the application on Facebook developer but my friend is not.
I have already approved following permissions from Facebook(see attached screen shot)

[image]
And below is the permission which I am using in my code-

```
FBSession* sess = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"user_birthday",@"email",@"user_education_history",@"user_work_history",@"user_hometown",@"read_stream",@"user_about_me",@"user_posts",@"publish_actions",nil]];
```

And here is the code to getting the timeline-

```
 NSString *urlStringFacebook = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?format=json&&access_token=%@&&limit=90",[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData]];
```

If I submit the read_stream permission to Facebbok for review the reject it due to the following reason(see screenshot below)-

[image]

And one more thing when I login with my account they ask me to allow for news feed(read_stream) permission but when my friend login they don't ask for that permission.

When I try to get the same thing on Graph API explorer then the data comes fine.
Please let me know what I am missing in the whole process.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/me/feed` instead of `/me/home`, with the already granted `user_posts` permission this should work. This endpoint also returns other posts from the user's timeline, not only those from the user himself (`/me/posts`)...

Comment: There is any difference between /me/home and /me/feed. As I run the command on graph explorer these both are giving me the different feeds.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `/me/home` without `read_stream` as outlined by @luschn. And as this permission is no longer granted, you need to fall back to `/me/feed` IMHO. There is no way to get the complete newsfeed via an App anymore.

Comment: Tobi, I tested with /me/feed but this provides me the feeds which is posted by me or in which I tagged in.

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote. `/me/home` is not an option anymore I guess because of the granting policy of the necessary permission `read_stream`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/home#readperms You will not be able to get the whole newsfeed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Home Timeline post using user_posts.

[image]

Using `/me/feed` you can get all post from others and you. go to Developer graph API Explorer [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: But I didn't get any timeline feeds from non develper facebook. I have all these permission from facebook.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I tested with /me/feed but this provides me the feeds which is posted by me or in which I tagged in and I need all feeds.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `/me/home`, which needs `read_stream` as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/home

...and that permission will not get approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-read_stream

**Use `/me/posts` or `/me/feed` instead, those endpoints need `user_posts` and you got that permission approved already**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Btw, this is explained very well in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features

Comment: `/me/posts` only returns the user's own posts, right? I think `/me/feed` would be the right call.

Comment: Yes this will return only post by me.

Comment: oh, my mistake. will change it. i got confused, it´s still early...or so :)

Comment: Yes I agree, and I tested with /me/feed but this provides me the feeds which is posted by me or which posted on my wall but I need all feeds like home.

Comment: that´s not possible anymore, for privacy reasons. as you can read in my answer, you would need read_stream for that, and you will not get it approved.

Comment: what about development of custom application embedded web browser that will login to FB like any web browser and strip down the HTML feed ?  use http://jsoup.org/ to remove strip down data from HTML  , might use apcahe common http lib to siumlate a browser behavior ?

Comment: please stick to your thread, no need to comment in several other threads with the same question.